# how to setting directory path postgresql for install driver php cpanel

Tags: php, postgresql, centos, cpanel

I want asking about installing driver php postgresql-9.1

I got error message :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /home/adminku/public_html/index.php on line 2
```

When I googling and trying to installing the driver with using easyapache, the problem installing driver show that the directory is no found,

I change the directory data postgresql to another path, because issue partition from my webmaster, but he can't setting about postgresql

and I found article http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/Php/ModulePgsql

it show i can make costum directory :

```
Notes
EasyApache searches the following locations for the psql binary:
    /usr/bin/
    /usr/local/bin/ 
It then runs psql --version to determine the PostgreSQL version on your system.
EasyApache searches the following locations for the pg_config binary:
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin 
If the binary is not found, this module will be skipped.
If you enable this option, --with-pgsql=directory will be added to PHP's configuration options.
```

1. have anyone try use this module with costum directory?
2. in my php.ini the extension using dll not so like usual centOS i knowed. my bos said, it's default from cpanel, but when i try to search php_pgsql.dll with locate, i can't found it, is it because that dll not found? or because my directory engine change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile apache with postgreSQL support with easyapache, it will solve your issue.